# html/css Images sometimes not loading

Tags: html, css, windows, image

On my locally hosted website of a file, some images sometimes look really weird or dont appear at all, when zooming all the images work again. The code is of course just a little snippet of the whole. Here is an image of how its supposed to look:  [How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teAgb.jpg) 
  And here one of how it sometimes is:
[How it sometimes is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1YO0.jpg)

Edit: The images change to weird or not at all there, when reloading the page.

//css code

```
.GPU1{

  background-color: #595959;
  border: 2.5px black solid;

  margin-left: -1000px;
  margin-right: 10px;

  transform: translateY(-125%);

  height: 10%;

  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;

  display: flex;
}

.GPU1Pic{
  margin-top: 130px;


  transform: translateX(-340%);
}

.GPU1Name{
  font-size: 25pt;

  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 2px black;


  margin-bottom: 150px;
  padding: 2px;
  transform: translateX(+46%);

  align-self: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.GPU1Price{
  font-size: 25pt;

  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 2px black;

  margin-top: 200px;

  transform: translateX(-80%);
}

.GPU1Button{

  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;


  transform: translateX(-60%);

  border: 0.5px black solid;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 2px black;

  background-color: gray;
  color: white;

  cursor: pointer;
}
```

// html code

```
   <div class = "GPU1">
      <h1 class = "GPU1Name">AMD Radeon RX 570</h1>
      <h2 class = "GPU1Price">140€-160€</h2>
      <button class = "GPU1Button" onclick="GPU1()" type="button">
         Leistung</button>
     <img class = "GPU1Pic" src="Website Bilder\GPU's\AMD Radeon RX 570.jpg" height="95px" width="150px">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you resize the image, it gets cropped. You can try to make something like this:

```css
.imgContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.imgContainer img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="imageSrc" />
</div>
```

The containing div with essentially crop the image by hiding the overflow.

Comment: Hey, that for some reason made my image not appear at all, dont know why, still thanks for trying to help^^

Comment: Have you only copied it or also added  `class = "GPU1Pic" src="Website Bilder\GPU's\AMD Radeon RX 570.jpg"` and all your settigns?

Comment: I added my settings and everything ele, but it just didnt show up anymore even after reloading the page a few times

Comment: That's really strange! Did you not get any other help from anybody else?

Comment: Not yet,I asked on another website, so I am just working on other stuff while waiting for some suggestions